# How to send header in swagger request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swagger, rails-api

I  secure api with authentication name and password but How to send parameters in header from swagger

My code is

```
 Swagger::Docs::Generator::set_real_methods

    # start swagger actions
    swagger_controller :users, "Users"

    swagger_api :signup do
        summary "SignUp"
        param :form, :first_name, :string, :required, "First Name"
        param :form, :last_name, :string, :required, "Last Name"
        param :form, :phone_no, :string, :required, "Phone Number"
        param :form, :email, :string, :required, "Email"
        param :form, :address, :string, :optional, "Address"
        param :form, :password, :string, :required, "Password"
        param :form, :password_confirmation, :string, :required, "Confirm Password"
    end
```

How do I customize it to send header parameters along with it

Answer (score 0):

You should be setting `param :header` instead of form.